# How do I integrate $X'' + \frac1xX' = 0$ where $X$ is a function of $x$?

Tags: calculus, integration, ordinary-differential-equations

I think I have to integrate twice to get a solution for $X$ in terms of $x$ but I don't know how to. I've tried to treat it as a second order ODE but I don't think it works.
Here $X = X(x)$ and $X' = dX/dx$

$$X'' + \frac1xX' = 0$$

Sorry for clarification I want to solve the equation, but I'm pretty sure I need to integrate it to do that

Comment: Do you want to integrate, or do you want to solve the differential equation?

Comment: Hi, thanks for editting. I want to solve the differential equation but a hint I was given said integrate twice, I've tried to integrate but I'm a bit confused on how to go about it for this particular question.

Comment: Hint: This is equivalent to $$(xX')'=xX''+X'=x\left(X''+\frac1xX'\right)=0.$$

Comment: By letting $u(x) = X'(x)$ it reduces to a first-order ODE, which you can solve via separation of variables or integrating factor.

Comment: @CBBAM It can't be solved on **all** of $\mathbb R.$

Answer (score 0):

Notice that if we consider $Y = X'$ then $Y' = X''$ and the equation becomes $Y' + \frac{1}{x}Y = 0$ which is a separable first order differential equation which you can solve for $Y$, and then solve for $X$.